# How to pass custom object for graph point on HighCharts Android

Tags: android, graph, highcharts, point

How to pass custom object for graph point on HighCharts Android ?
I want to pass extra information other than x and y values for point on graph. That extra information i want to use in tooltip.
How to achieve this on Android ?

I tried something like this, but it did not work.

```
data class GraphPoint(val x:Float, val y:Float, val date:Long)

val readings = ArrayList<List<GraphPoint>>()
readings.add(GraphPoint(1f, 10f, 1657255313)
readings.add(GraphPoint(2f, 5f, 1657255351)
readings.add(GraphPoint(3f, 20f, 1662612113)

val scatter = HIScatter()
scatter.data = readings
```

Comment: It seems you ask the same question here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android/issues/237  We work as a single team across all support platforms, so for the future please do not duplicate your topics on multiple channels - the answers are being delivered asap anyway. Regards!

Comment: Oh Okay. It was not answered for couple of days on Github. And it was a bit urgent for me, So i thought of seeking help here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android/issues/237

For that case, we will need to use maps. In tooltip, we will need to refer to point parameter by its map key equivalent (e.g. point.{key_name}). Check out this example:

```
    HIChartView chartView = findViewById(R.id.chartview1);
    HIOptions options = new HIOptions();

    HILegend legend = new HILegend();
    legend.setEnabled(false);
    options.setLegend(legend);

    HITooltip tooltip = new HITooltip();
    tooltip.setHeaderFormat("<span style=\"font-size:11px\">{series.name}</span><br>");
    tooltip.setPointFormat("<b>X: {point.x:.2f}%</b> <b>Y: {point.y:.2f}%</b><br/>Date: point.date");
    options.setTooltip(tooltip);

    HIScatter series1 = new HIScatter();

    HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("date", 1657255313);
    map1.put("x", 1);
    map1.put("y", 10);

    HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("date", 1657255351);
    map2.put("x", 2);
    map2.put("y", 5);;

    HashMap<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put("date", 1662612113);
    map3.put("x", 3);
    map3.put("y", 20);


    HashMap[] series1_data = new HashMap[] { map1, map2, map3 };
    series1.setData(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(series1_data)));
    options.setSeries(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(series1)));

    chartView.setOptions(options);
```